# How to refuse providing CV/resume?

Tags: contracts, communication, resume

I have a static page where I describe expertise and services provided and sample work. Whenever I get approached by potential clients or recruiters I'm being asked for my CV/resume.

I tried to delete all my data on Linkedin to stop being approached by Linkedin recruiters looking to hire employees, middlemen and outsourcing companies with 4th-hand projects.

Even though I've deleted my Linkedin data, and indicate that all details are on the static page mentioned above, recruiters are still trying to view my Linkedin page and they keep asking me for my CV/resume.

I find it hard to communicate that I'm purely interested in providing services as a freelancer/contractor/consultant and not as an employee.

I have a few questions here:

1. How can I stop getting these requests for my CV ?
2. How do I communicate that the CV is not required as part of any process of me or my company working with a client ?
3. Is there any point in providing the person with a CV ?
4. Is it acceptable in terms of business to not provide a CV, and instead provide a detailed list of expertise and services provided ?
5. Is a request for CV/resume indicative that the position is for an outsourcing company and not for a product company ?

P.S. One reason for me not wanting to provide my CV is that it's free advertising for my previous employers, on the other hand if I want to advertise myself I have to pay hundreds of dollars on Google ads, so the asymmetry is visible.

Answer (score 2):

Turn the problem around and ask: What would my potential clients want to see to be able to evaluate if this person has the experience and is this person easy to work with?

I fully understand your wanting to communicate in a certain way, but potential clients often expect to see certain information in a certain format. When we do not meet prospects in a manner that they expect, that puts up a barrier to being hired for the project. So, are you really wanting to control how they get their information or do you want the project? When you focus on controlling the information flow, you might be telling them that you are a challenge to work with and they might do better by getting someone else. Is that the message that you want them to read into your actions?

Ask the question: do you even want to deal with recruiters? If not, then put together something that will always tell a recruiter to find someone else.

1. You can't stop the requests for CV/resume. Deal with it in a manner that communicates the message that you want to give.
2. To communicate that the CV is not needed, build a consistent message via other means such as direct mailings, web site, blog, your booth at the trade shows, your contributed articles in trade magazines, white papers, brochures, and cold calling on prospects.
3. Point of providing a CV? That all depends on who receives it. The person receiving it determines the point of providing one.
4. Not providing a CV? See #2.
5. No, I've had direct prospects ask for a resume - because that is the way that they know how to evaluate me and my company. I've also had clients ask for that so that they could show to outside investors that they have a competent team.

Asymmetry always exists. Instead of worrying about that, focus on your advantages and the benefits of working with you.